# Redirect loop on checkout

Tags: redirection, commerce

I'm trying to resolve a checkout redirecting issue. I've inherited a project and the site is using a multi-page checkout process. After entering all information and clicking the continue button, it goes into some kind of redirect loop.

You can see the resulting redirects on this screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

I'm only guessing, but it appears to be caused by commerce_checkout_router call in commerce/modules/checkout/commerce_checkout.module.

I found the following code.

```php
function commerce_checkout_menu()
 $items['checkout/%commerce_order/%commerce_checkout_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Checkout',
    'page callback' => 'commerce_checkout_router',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'access arguments' => array('access checkout'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'includes/commerce_checkout.pages.inc',
);
```

In /commerce/modules/checkout/includes/commerce_checkout.pages.inc, around line 34, the code is the following.

```php
if (!empty($target_uri) && $target_uri !== $_GET['q']) {
     drupal_goto($target_uri);
}
```

The checkout page where this happens is /checkout/[order number]/checkout, so I'm assuming this code is the issue.

The messages I get are the following.

> The webpage at http://mysite.local/checkout/44/review has resulted in too many redirects.
> The webpage at http://mysite.local/checkout/44/shipping has resulted in too many redirects.

It seems to alternate between the two, so I'm pretty sure they are redirecting to each other. The question is, why?

I've installed xdebug and set a breakpoint in the commerce_checkout.pages.inc file, at the conditional statement I list above, but it doesn't seem to break, so I don't know what to do.

I also turned on rules debugging, but I'm not sure I see anything that would indicate a redirect, just stuff like "Reacting on event Calculating the sell price of a product." fires, "Calculate taxes" fires, and "Collect rates: Delivery By Truck" fires.

I'd really appreciate some assistance in troubleshooting this. I have to get this store running ASAP.

Comment: Hey friend. I am having the SAME issue, ( though I see it in debugger, it does not cause the "too many redirects" message in browser).

Did you manage to solve the issue? If so, would you mind posting the answer, I will dump you karma for your trouble.  I had to resort to a somewhat hackish work-around to prevent my submit handlers on that form from being called twice.  Thanks!

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I never got this figured out and moved on to another task. You may want to ask on their support page on https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce, or join their irc channel, #drupal-commerce. I hope you are able to get this resolved.